# Re-signing ClickOnce by a patch installer

Tags: c#, clickonce, patch, sign

I have created an app which is being installed on a remote server, using Click-once and I have signed it. Now when I want to update it, I have to compile all my solution and send all of the application files. However I want to update a tiny DLL. If I send this little dll and paste it there

[image: Application File Not Valid]

I finally could re-sgn it using MageUI.exe. But I write a patch installer application. How can I sign a dll and insert it in application folder which application doesn't stop working?
I'm using .NET 3.5
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The application is strongly linked with it's manifest and the payload.

You could try and just Code Sign the dll with **Sign Tool** ([link here](http://www.digicert.com/code-signing/signcode-signtool-command-line.htm)) and replace it.